# Maximum feasible subsystem problem (MaxFS) in 2 variables

Tags: computational-geometry, linear-programming, linear-algebra

**Topic:**
The [maximum feasible subsystem problem](http://risorse.dei.polimi.it/maxfs/), which is generally NP-hard [1].

**Question:**
Are there special algorithms in case of only 2 variables (2D linear constraints)? The problem seems to be a lot less complex in my humble opinion but is this true? Can you guys point me to any algorithms/papers for this limited case with reduced computational complexity?

**References:**
[1] E. Amaldi and V. Kann, [The complexity and approximability of finding maximum feasible subsystems of linear relations](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download;jsessionid=E5F2A09B65113E8B30F82BEF29FF00FD?doi=10.1.1.43.9283&rep=rep1&type=pdf) Theoretical Computer Science, vol. 147, pp. 181–210, 1993.